# Laravel accessor is returning the whole object instead of a single field

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6, accessor, eloquent-relationship

I've got the following relationship between `MenuItem` and `Category`:

**Menu Item Model**

```
public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Category');
    }

public function getCategoryNameAttribute()
    {
        return $this->attributes['category_name'] = $this->category->name;
    }
```

**Category Model**

```
public function menuItems()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\MenuItem');
    }
```

Now, from my controller, when returning a list of all menu items I want to return `category_name` along with the results. As you noticed in the code above I created an accessor `getCategoryNameAttribute` to get the name.

The method that returns a list of all menu items in my controller is:

```
public function index()
    {
        $menuItems = $this->menuItem->all();

        foreach ($menuItems as $menuItem) {
            $menuItem['category_name'] = $menuItem->category_name;
        }

        return $menuItems;
    }
```

If I do `dd($menuItems);` right after `$menuItems = $this->menuItem->all();` I get:

```
[
        "id" => 1
        "name" => "Hailee Ondricka"
        "category_id" => 1
        "side" => 0
        "side_only" => 0
        "description" => "Amet delectus exercitationem neque tenetur aliquam. Et repudiandae nam nam voluptates laboriosam autem. Natus quo quia ea. Explicabo reprehenderit consequatur quia aliquam incidunt."
        "image" => "https://lorempixel.com/640/480/?39201"
        "available" => 0
        "active" => 0
        "created_at" => "2020-06-21 00:41:02"
        "updated_at" => "2020-06-21 00:41:02"
      ]
```

but after the foreach in which I'm appending `category_name` I'm getting:

```
"id" => 1
    "name" => "Krista Donnelly"
    "category_id" => 1
    "side" => false
    "side_only" => false
    "description" => "Sapiente est maiores non voluptatum odio placeat. Cum enim aut odit autem aut autem. Quasi excepturi omnis laborum aut officia tempora accusamus."
    "image" => "https://lorempixel.com/640/480/?96389"
    "available" => true
    "active" => false
    "created_at" => "2020-06-21 00:42:49"
    "updated_at" => "2020-06-21 00:42:49"
    "category_name" => "Dr. Christelle Purdy MD"
    "category" => array:4 [
      "id" => 1
      "name" => "Dr. Christelle Purdy MD"
      "created_at" => "2020-06-21 00:42:49"
      "updated_at" => "2020-06-21 00:42:49"
    ]
  ]
```

As you can see in the result, I do get `category_name` but I'm also getting the whole `category` object associated to that category, why is that? how do I prevent the whole object of being returned?

Comment: this is because you have loaded the `category` relationship when you accessed it `$this->category->name` via the `category_name` accessor ... the relationships that are loaded are included when serializing the model

Comment: @lagbox oh I see. Any way to get around this?